# Problem to implement route forwarding method

Tags: kubernetes

I have developed one application using minikube and one pod. I am using IPVS mode here. The application works when I have used Masq forwarding methods. But it does not work for route forwarding methods. Should I need to configure anything when I am using route forwarding method?

Here I have attached IPVS list for Masq and Route forwarding method.

```
  # ipvsadm  -Ln
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  10.96.0.1:443 wlc
  -> 147.214.68.51:8443           Masq    1      2          0
TCP  10.96.0.10:53 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.2:53                Masq    1      0          0
  -> 172.17.0.3:53                Masq    1      0          0
TCP  10.108.116.175:5000 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Masq    1      0          0
TCP  127.0.0.1:32673 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Masq    1      0          0
TCP  147.214.68.51:32673 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Masq    1      0          0
TCP  172.17.0.1:32673 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Masq    1      0          0
TCP  10.96.0.10:9153 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.2:9153              Masq    1      0          0
  -> 172.17.0.3:9153              Masq    1      0          0
UDP  10.96.0.10:53 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.2:53                Masq    1      0          0
  -> 172.17.0.3:53                Masq    1      0          0



  # ipvsadm -Ln
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  10.96.0.1:443 wlc
  -> 147.214.68.51:8443           Route   1      0          0
TCP  10.96.0.10:53 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.2:53                Route   1      0          0
  -> 172.17.0.3:53                Route   1      0          0
TCP  10.108.116.175:5000 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Route   1      0          0
TCP  127.0.0.1:32673 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Route   1      0          0
TCP  147.214.68.51:32673 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Route   1      3          0
TCP  172.17.0.1:32673 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Route   1      0          0
TCP  10.96.0.10:9153 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.2:9153              Route   1      0          0
  -> 172.17.0.3:9153              Route   1      0          0
UDP  10.96.0.10:53 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.2:53                Route   1      0          0
  -> 172.17.0.3:53                Route   1      0          0
```

Comment: Don't post images when text will do. copy and paste the text (commands and output) from your terminal instead. Use the `{}` icon in the stackexchange editor to format it as code. Text is searchable, editable, re-usable and legible in any screen size. It also works for vision impaired users. Images are none of those things and, worse, (from your POV) actively discourages people from making any effort to read your and answer your question. i know i'm not going to bother spending 10 minutes squinting at it to try to figure out what's going on.